# CakePHP 2 user database/password migration for Cakephp 4

Tags: authentication, cakephp, upgrade, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-4.x

My customer has program which is made with CakePHP 2 (not my project) and he wants to upgrade it to newest CakePHP.

I noticed that there was tutorial for Custom Password Hasher (legacy / sha1 + blowfish) but it has been deprecated since 4.0 and should use authentication plugin.

How i can make that kind of procedure without touching core code which check if password needs rehash and then create new hash on database?

On loadAuthenticator i cannot put different hasher for that.

Comment: The authentication plugin lets you load whatever hashers you want, including a [fallback password hasher](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/password-hashers.html#fallback) that will let you authenticate both old and new passwords. Documentation about how to upgrade old hashes is [here](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/migration-from-the-authcomponent.html#migrating-hashing-upgrade-logic).

Answer (score 0):

Yes but old valid user gives on login "Authentication\Authenticator\Result Object ( [_status:protected] => FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND [_data:protected] => [_errors:protected] => Array ( [Password] => Array ( ) ) )"

and newly created user with new has Authentication\Authenticator\Result Object ( [_status:protected] => SUCCESS etc..

I have made that check with that tutorial but how it can be valid if that not "exists"? SQL-query returns 1 row with old users email.

```
public function login() {
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('login');


    if($this->request->is(['post','put'])) {


        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();

        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $authService = $this->Authentication->getAuthenticationService();

            // Assuming you are using the `Password` identifier.
            if ($authService->identifiers()->get('Password')->needsPasswordRehash()) {
                // Rehash happens on save.
                $user = $this->Users->get($this->Authentication->getIdentityData('id'));
                $user->password = $this->request->getData('password');
                $this->Users->save($user);
            }

            // Redirect to a logged in page
            return $this->redirect([
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

It will never goes inside "result->isvalid()" with old user.